# Replace text within a cell in Google Spreadsheets using a script

Tags: html, templates, replace, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a basic signature generator for Gmail using Google Spreadsheet. I have the HTML template but I can't expect everyone to know how to edit it, so I am trying to create a spreadsheet that will generate the HTML output in a CELL. Then users would copy the contents of that cell, paste it in notepad, save it as HTML, open it, and copy and paste it into GMail.

I know how convoluted this approach is, so any ideas are welcome.

What I have tried is to have a spreadsheet with fields that I would get through a script:

[Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS4NU.png)

Then, I want to be able to generate HTML using my template:

[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHcRO.png)

My approach so far was to have all that HTML in a single cell, and using a function, **replace each placeholder with a cell value**. I have seen a lot of examples on how to perform replace in the whole cell, but I can't find anything that would apply to this.

This is how far I've got:

```
function Signature() {
 var Nombre = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C5').getValue()
 var Titulo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C6').getValue()
 var Correo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C7').getValue()
 var Telefono = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C8').getValue()
 var Imagen = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C9').getValue()
 var HTML = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E5').getValue()
}
```

(and I do realize that's pretty much nothing)

Needless to say I am not a developer and I don't expect anyone to solve the problem for me (aka get job for free). I would just like to be oriented in the right direction in terms of which method to use or a different and maybe easier approach.

Thanks a lot

Comment: to make a valid question, you must show an attempt related to the task. only getting sheet ranges is too little as it does not show an attempt or what went wrong with your tries.

Comment: You would have spent the same amount of time in saying "You could try this" instead of attempting to lecture me. And maybe I missed that *requirement* in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice? :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Signature() {
 var Nombre = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C5').getValue()
 var Titulo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C6').getValue()
 var Correo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C7').getValue()
 var Telefono = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C8').getValue()
 var Imagen = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C9').getValue()
 var HTML = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E5').getValue()




var _HTMLTemplate = "in_quotations_all_your_html_code"+use_plus_sing _to_insert_variable+"continue_your_HTML_Code"
return _htmlTemplate


}
```

ex:

```
var _html = '<span id="nombreContainer" style="color:blue;">'+ Nombre + '</span>'
```

Comment: Thank you much @JuanDiegoAntezana. I had tried that but using " instead of '. Worked like a charm. Thank you!